# Sum of 2 sums php

Tags: php, mysql

I need help with Sum of 2 sum numbers. 
Well I have table where showing user sum numbers.
At end of table I need to make row which showing sum of all numbers.

Table:

[image: Table]

So on blue row I need sum of all numbers up.
My code:

```
 $groupQuery =
    "SELECT r.broj_rac AS racun, COUNT(stavka) AS stavka, d.naziv1 AS dobavljac, SUM(iznos_osnovica) AS osnovica, SUM(iznos_porez) AS porez, SUM(moze_se_odbiti) AS odbiti, SUM(nemoze_se_odbiti) AS neodbiti, SUM(neoporezivo) AS neoporezivo, SUM(ukupno) AS ukupno1, r.sveukupno AS sveukupno 
    FROM racuni AS r
    LEFT JOIN dobavljaci AS d
    ON d.sifra = r.dobavljac
    WHERE partner = '".$_SESSION['sifra_partnera']."'
    GROUP by broj_rac";
```

Is it possible to make something like `SUM(SUM(ukupno AS ukupno1) AS ukupno2)`?

Comment: why not handle the calculation of the various final sums in PHP?

Comment: @RamRaider I don't know, should I change it to php?

Comment: yes, because if you are displaying the rows you already processing these data, so summing in code would hurt much less than all these massive queries. SQL engine is not a calculator :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to add a total row, rather than sum columns as other answers are suggesting, so something like this should work if you just want to include a row which totals the `osnovica` and `porez` values:

```
$groupQuery =
    SELECT  r.broj_rac AS racun, 
            COUNT(stavka) AS stavka, 
            d.naziv1 AS dobavljac, 
            SUM(iznos_osnovica) AS osnovica, 
            SUM(iznos_porez) AS porez, 
            SUM(moze_se_odbiti) AS odbiti, 
            SUM(nemoze_se_odbiti) AS neodbiti, 
            SUM(neoporezivo) AS neoporezivo, 
            SUM(ukupno) AS ukupno1, 
            r.sveukupno AS sveukupno 
    FROM racuni AS r
    LEFT JOIN dobavljaci AS d
    ON d.sifra = r.dobavljac
    WHERE partner = '".$_SESSION['sifra_partnera']."'
    GROUP by broj_rac

    UNION

    SELECT  'TOTAL' AS racun, 
            '' AS stavka, 
            '' AS dobavljac, 
            SUM(iznos_osnovica) AS osnovica, 
            SUM(iznos_porez) AS porez, 
            '' AS odbiti, 
            '' AS neodbiti, 
            '' AS neoporezivo, 
            '' AS ukupno1, 
            '' AS sveukupno 
    FROM racuni AS r
    LEFT JOIN dobavljaci AS d
    ON d.sifra = r.dobavljac
    WHERE partner = '".$_SESSION['sifra_partnera']."'"
```

In the second half of the `UNION`, you could also perform aggregate functions on any other fields you wished to summarise in the total row, for example `SUM(ukupno) AS ukupno1` or `AVG(ukupno) AS ukupno1` if you wanted the total sum or average of `ukupno` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query

```
SELECT 
(
    SUM(COL_1)
  + SUM(COL_2)
  + SUM(COL_3)
) as `Total` 
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
SELECT 
   Val1,
   Val2,
   Val3,
   (Val1 + Val2 + Val3) as 'Total'
FROM MyTable
```

or if you just want one row:

```
SELECT 
   SUM(Val1) as 'Val1',
   SUM(Val2) as 'Val2',
   SUM(Val3) as 'Val3',
   (SUM(Val1) + SUM(Val2) + SUM(Val3)) as 'Total'
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
SELECT 
    (
        SUM(COL_1)
      + SUM(COL_2)
      + SUM(COL_3)
    ) as `Total` 
FROM TABLE_NAME
```